# Variable argument pairs in MATLAB functions

Tags: matlab, function, variadic-functions, optional-parameters, name-value

I'm trying to develop a function that contains multiple arguments.  To be as robust as possible, I want to be able to call my function as follows:

```
foo( x, y, z, 'OptionalArg1', bar, 'OptionalArg2', blah, 'OptionalArg3', val )
```

I want my function to be robust enough to contain any combination of these arguments in any order. I also need to be able to set defaults if the argument is not provided.  Is there a standard way to do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would be to use the [`inputParser`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.html) class, with the `addParameters` function.

In short, your code would look like:

```
function foo(x,y,z,varargin)

p=inputParser;

validationFcn=@(x)isa(x,'double')&&(x<5); % just a random example, add anything
addParameter(p,'OptionalArg1',defaultvalue, validationFcn);
% same for the other 2, with your conditions

%execute
parse(p,varargin{:});

% get the variables
bar=p.Results.OptionalArg1;
% same for the other 2


% foo
```

Alternatively, you could write your own as I did ([example here](https://github.com/CERN/TIGRE/blob/master/MATLAB/Algorithms/SIRT.m#L211)). The code there is easily modifiable to have your own input parser (you just need to change the `opts`, and add a `switch` for each new `opt`.

But the `inputParser` is easier, and clearer to use.