# Using a function with optional inputted parameters

Tags: matlab, function, scripting, optional-parameters, variable-declaration

I have been struggling with this problem for about a week. I have been trying to convert a script into a function for research purposes. The problem is that the code has a lot of conditional existing statements for variables, so certain variables won't exist in the workspace when they are checked for (this is why it works well as a script).

Varargin is not a solution to this problem because some of the function INPUTS won't exist.

**Workspace**

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
var4 = 4
```

**Code to turn into function**

```
if exist('var3','var')
   disp('var 3 exists')
else
   disp('var 3 does not exist')
end
```

The following function will NOT work because it is calling variable 3 which does not exist.

**calling function**

```
runCode(var1, var2, var3, var4)
```

I originally wrote this prior my function and made the code check for `isnan` instead of `exist`, but it's not great practice and since the function is called often, I don't want to have to update this function setup whenever changes to the code are made.

```
  if ~exist("var1", "var"), var1= NaN; end 
  if ~exist("var2", "var"), var2= NaN; end 
  if ~exist("var3", "var"), var3= NaN; end 
  if ~exist("var4", "var"), var4= NaN; end
```

I don't want to use `eval`, and loading the workspace has caused me issues because a bunch of figures are present and it messes up the figure count in a later portion of the code. The only ideas I have right know is have a setup script for the previous if statements, or somehow save all of the workspace data into a struct or something and then assign the values the corresponding `who` string (gives workspace variable names).

Thanks for any ideas you guys might have

Comment: So you have a bunch of variables in your function that may exist in the workspace or not. If your code depends on the existence of these variables you won't have a choice but to check if they exist and create them if they don't. There is no way around that. I personally would wrap each occurence of a variable with a function, e.g. runCode( safevar(var1), safevar(var2), safevar(var3), safevar(var4) ) and check for the existence within safevar and create the variable via eval if it does not exist.

Comment: I would approch this problem using the [inputParser](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.html)  object. You can designate name-value pairs so you could call the function, `runCode('var1', var1, 'var3', var3, ...)` and have the inputParser assign a default value to any `var#`'s not entered. Alternative to using name value pairs, the input parser lets you expand structs, so you could have a struct with fieldnames, `{'var1', 'var3'} then pass the struct into `runCode(S)`. Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276776/variable-arguments-in-matlab)

Comment: “loading the workspace has caused me issues because a bunch of figures are present and it messes up the figure count in a later portion of the code.” I don’t understand this. Some code depends on whether there are figure windows open? You can’t fix that changing your code to a function, figure windows are global things, the count is identical in the base workspace and in the workspace of a function you call.

Comment: As I understand it, you have a script that does something different depending on which variables exist. You can do this in a function too, using `evalin`, but I don’t know if that is any better than keeping the script. I don’t see any other workarounds. A function should only read values passed into it, so you need to call the function with the relevant variables. It should not behave differently if a variable is defined or not. I’d say keep it as a script!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of the feedback. Since the function I want to call is sometimes called from the same place but with different variables existing, I can't vary how the parameters are set up. So, what I have done might make you guys cry but I have a setup script which I call before the function which checks if the parameters exist or not, and set them to a NaN if they don't. Its the exact same solution I had before but in a script.

PS I agree this should be left a script but they really want it to be a function ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4):

The current script behaves differently depending on the existence of a set of variables with pre-defined names. This is difficult to replicate in a function, because a function *should* not read the calling workspace's values. This is possible to do, of course:

```
try
   var1 = evalin('caller','var1');
catch
   % do nothing, the variable doesn't exist in the caller, it won't exist here
end
```

But this **really** bad practice, and no different from a script. And OP specifically said to not want to use `eval`.

There is an alternative, which I'm hesitant to recommend because it is almost as evil as the above. We're going to define a function whose input arguments are not based on order, but on name:

```
runCode(var1)
```

will behave differently than

```
runCode(var2)
```

But the following two statements will behave identically:

```
runCode(var1,var2)
runCode(var2,var1)
```

Skeeved out? You should be!

The trick is to use [`inputname`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html) as follows:

```
function runCode(varargin)
for ii = 1:nargin
   switch inputname(ii)
      case 'var1', var1 = varargin{ii};
      case 'var2', var2 = varargin{ii};
      case 'var3', var3 = varargin{ii};
      case 'var4', var4 = varargin{ii};
      otherwise,   error('Illegal input argument')
   end
end
```

The rest of the function would be the body of OP's script, which contains code as follows:

```
if exist('var1','var')
   % ...
end
```

That is, first we see which variables are passed to the function, next we see which variables exist. It should be possible to rewrite the script itself to replace the `exist` checks with lookups into a list of input argument names.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the inputs be in arg pairs, so you call it like:

```
runCode ( 'var1', 123, 'var2', 456, 'var4', 789)
```

Where your function is

```
function runCode ( varargin )
  defaults.var1 =[];
  defaults.var2 =[];
  defaults.var3 =[];
  defaults.var4 =[];

  for ii = 1:2:nargin
    if isfield ( defaults, varargin{ii} )
      defaults.(varargin{ii}) = varargin{ii+1};
    else
      Throw error?
    end
```

Then you change the check on var3 to check if the value `defaults.var3` is empty.